# Efficient SpriteKit Spatial Hashing Collision Detection For 2D Game

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I've been looking around for tutorials on spatial hashing for Objective C or spriteKit. I've found examples in other languages, but I can't Seem to figure it out. I've gotten this far but I'm stuck.

This Loads Enemy Sprites To An NSMutableDictionary, I divide Their x,y positions by 64 to get their cellID (I use cellID as a key for the enemy in NSMutableDictionary).

```
- (void)loadEnemies {

    TMXObjectGroup *enemiesGroup = [self.map groupNamed:@"enemies"];
    for (NSDictionary *enemyDict in enemiesGroup.objects) {

    NSString *enemyType = enemyDict[@"type"];
    NSString *firstFrameName = 
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@1.png",enemyType];
    CGPoint enemyPosition = 
    CGPointMake([enemyDict[@"x"] floatValue], [enemyDict[@"y"] floatValue]);


    CGPoint cellNumber = 
    CGPointMake(enemyPosition.x / 64, enemyPosition.y / 64);
    NSString *CellID = 
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",NSStringFromCGPoint(cellNumber)];

    SMCEnemy *enemy =  [[NSClassFromString(enemyType)alloc]
    initEnemyWithImageNamed:firstFrameName Position:enemyPosition];

    enemy.position = enemyPosition;
    enemy.player = self.cat;
    enemy.map = self.map;
    enemy.delegate = self;

    [self.map addChild:enemy];
    enemy.zPosition = 900;

    //enemies added to NSMutableDictionary
    [self.enemeyDictionary setObject:enemy forKey:CellID];
}
}
```

Ive added enemies to an NSMutableDictionary using CellID as a key.

This Checks For Collisions with the player, I first check the distance between the player and each enemy; if the distance is less than 1000, then enemy becomes active.

```
- (void)checkForEnemyCollisions:(SMCEnemy *)enemy {

     CGFloat distance = CGPointDistance(enemy.posiiton, self.player.position);

    if (distance < 1000){
    enemy.isActive = YES;
    } else {
     enemy.isActive = NO;
    }

    if (enemy.isActive && enemy.life > 0) {
    //cat hurt
    if ((CGRectIntersectsRect(self.cat.collisionBoundingBox, enemy.collisionBoundingBox) || CGRectIntersectsRect(self.cat.collisionBoundingBox, enemy.attackBox)) && self.cat.isActive && !enemy.hidden && enemy.canHurtPlayer){

    enemy.attackBox = CGRectNull;
    if (enemy.position.x < self.cat.position.x) {
        [self.cat bounceWithDirection:1];
    }else{
        [self.cat bounceWithDirection:-1];
        }

     [self.cat tookHit:self.cat];
     [self movementCoolDownForCharacter:self.cat coolDownTime:.5];
}

// enemy hurt
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(enemy.collisionBoundingBox, self.cat.attackBox)&&  !enemy.isHurt && enemy.isStun && !enemy.hidden) {
CGRect intersection = CGRectIntersection(enemy.collisionBoundingBox,self.cat.attackBox);

        _hit.position = CGPointMake(intersection.origin.x, intersection.origin.y);
        _hit.hidden = NO;

        SKAction *DoneAction = [SKAction runBlock:(dispatch_block_t)^() {
            _hit.hidden = YES;
        }];

        SKAction *moveLaserActionWithDone = [SKAction sequence:@[enemy.hitAnim,DoneAction]];
        [_hit runAction:moveLaserActionWithDone];

        enemy.isHurt = YES;
        [enemy tookHit:self.cat];
        [self movementCoolDownForCharacter:enemy coolDownTime:.5];
}
}
```

The Update Method

```
- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {
        NSTimeInterval delta = currentTime - self.previousUpdateTime;
        self.previousUpdateTime = currentTime;
        if (delta > 0.1) {
        delta = 0.1;
        }

        for (SMCEnemy *enemy in self.enemies) {
         [self checkForEnemyCollisions:enemy];
        }
        }
```

I want to use spatial hashing instead of going through every enemy item in the enemyArray to improve performance.

Im stuck Any Help would be really awesome! :D

Comment: You're not really explaining your problem all that well. What exactly do you _want_ to achieve and what _have_ you achieved with the above?

Comment: @nickfalk sorry about that, I updated my question with more information. thank you for responding!

Comment: If this is _just_ for collision-checking it is _really_ not the way to go about it in SpriteKit as it already has a very robust physics-engine built in that can be used for collision-detection (have a look at `SKPhysicsBody` if this is the case) .

Comment: @nickfalk I've used SpriteKits collision physics-engine, but I've learned that for my needs. Implementing my own collisions works best

Comment: It would make sense to use hashing to trigger attacks for instance, but doesn't your current problems actually confirm that your own collision-detection-system does _not_ work best? It is seldom a good idea to fight the core functionality of a framework.

Comment: Anyways, as you're already storing the enemies to a dictionary, isn't it just a question of calculating the _keys_ based on the player position?